# pyinstaller .exe file doesn't work on another computer

Tags: python, file, makefile, pyinstaller

I have used pyinstaller to compile the py file into exe, on my computer it is working well
but when i am trying to download it on another computer it's always giving me error,
`FileNotFound: no such file or directory`  when i compiled the py file i added the python39.dll.
here is the command i used:

```
pyinstaller --noconfirm --onefile --console --add-binary "C:/Users/Usern/Desktop/dist/python39.dll;."  "C:/Users/Usern/Desktop/dist/m.py"
```

I am trying to create a file with this command:

```py
  f1 = open("C:\\Users\\Usern\\AppData\\Local\\Mine\\x.exe", "wb").write(x_req)
```

again in my computer that .exe file works well as should be but in another computer it does not work.

Comment: did you check if the user on the other computer is Usern?

Comment: You said you are getting that error when "trying to download" the exe, but I assume you're actually getting the error when you try to *run* the exe. Also, you should post the full stracktrace of the error, which you can get by running the .exe from a command prompt. Are there any paths in the program that are specific to your computer and not generic? Is the error about the `Usern\\AppData\\Local\\Mine\\x.exe` path that's in your question?

Comment: Just use `pyinstaller --onefile m.py` from the env you're using with `pyinstaller`

Comment: I'll be more specific, first of all no it is not usern but i changed it just to hide the name but i use os to get the name so that's not the problem, secondly i get the error when i try to create a file the command the i specified above is to create file

Comment: @ZONEX have you tried with the plain `pyinstaller --onefile` command? Same issue?

Comment: Yeah i did it like in the first time

Comment: but when i am not specify the python39.dll it is not work at all

Comment: It looks like you have hard-coded the file location in your program and that location (folder) doesn't exist on the target machine. That is the only way you get *File not found* when you open a file for writing. You need to make the location user-dependent, such as, the folder pointed to by `%USERPROFILE%`.

Answer (score 0):

The program is trying to pull in a file that isnt on the computer. I had the same problem when my program used an image, it had to be in the same directory.